# Report Title Not Centering with Column Groups

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a matrix with a column group for the months in the year. Normally, when I don't have column groups, I'll make the width of the body of the report the printing size, less the margin size. That way I can center the title that is in the header.

How do I center the title when I have column groups? If I leave extra space in the body for the printing size, it'll add that space on top of the space that each column in the column group takes up and will print a blank page after each page. But if I remove that space, then the header will only be centered according to the width of body of the report.

[image]

Comment: Please do not link to images. You can embed screenshots and other images directly into your question, which makes your question easier to read, and also means that the image will never get unlinked.

Comment: It wouldn’t let me embed it since I’m a new member.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge cells across column groups and non-group columns so you won't be able to centre the title if it's part of the tablix/matrix.

The easy way would be to move the Title to it's own textbox, set that the full width of the body and then the TextAlign property to Center, outside the tablix.